# Windows could not start the SQL Server service error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a problem when I run my web project. I get this error :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Then I found in SQL Server Configuration Manager that SQL Server Express stopped. When I'm trying to run SQL Server Express, another error appears:

> the request failed or the service did not respond in timely fashion. Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details

When I open `services.msc` to start SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS instance) then this error happens:

> Window could not start the sql server (SQLEXPRESS) on local Computer. For more information  review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 3417

Any solution to solve my problem? The version is SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

Comment: We need to see what the error is in the event log.

Comment: possible resolution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617402/the-request-failed-or-the-service-did-not-respond-in-a-timely-fashion However, as others have mentioned, the log will help determine what happened.

Comment: related question with Windows 10 specific elements:
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119606/unable-to-get-sql-server-2016-ctp3-service-to-start-on-windows-10

Answer (score 2):

Open SQL Server configuration manager (start-->Run-->SQLServerManager10.msc) and try to start the service. If there is a problem starting the service, locate the SQL server Error  log (in the SQL service configuration manager advanced tab there is a location or path of the error log) and post the output in the forum.